# How to map a point in plane A to a point in plane B

Tags: plane-geometry, transformational-geometry

I have a 3D point $P$ from Microsoft Kinect (relative to the Kinect camera plane - call it plane $A$), and I want to find point $P'$ that's mapped to $P$ on another plane (call it $B$) that I have an equation for ($ax + by + cz + d = 0$).

For example:
$P$ (on original plane $A$): $(1,2,3)$
Plane $B$: $2x + 3y + 4z + 5 = 0$
And I need to find $P'$, the mapping of $P$, but relative to plane $B$.

I understand that it can be done using a transformation matrix, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: What is meant by $(1,2,3)$? This is a point, not a plane. And what is a "map relative to a plane"? Do you mean the orthogonal projection of $P$ onto $B$?

Comment: $P$ is a point $(x,y,z)$. $A$ is the plane that $P$ is on (Kinect's plane). I'm not sure how to explain this. Let's say I have another plane, for example the floor - and I want to find coordinates of $P$ while looking at it from the floor's perspective (instead of Kinect's perspective)

Comment: Do you want to map $P$ onto a point $P'$ on the plane $B$ such that the connection vector $PP'$ is a normal vector of the plane $B$ (meaning it has a 90° angle with $B$)?

Comment: I think that you should forget planes and think of the points of view: you have the coordinates from the kinetc camera and you want to find the coordinates while looking from another point of view ( whose coordinates and view direction you should know)

Comment: Your questions make sense but I'm not sure how to answer since I'm still confused myself. The idea is this: say I want to track a person's hand according to their body. If the person moved / turned around without moving their hand, the hand position according to Kinect will change. but if in every frame I have the human body as a plane, the hand won't change position according to the body. And that's what I want.

Comment: If you’re having trouble describing your setup, including an illustration of it might be helpful.